# Flutter GridView.count shrinks when setState is called on one if its children

Tags: flutter, datagridview

I have 4 widgets that might be visible. They should be displayed 2 in a row, but I can't know in advance if widget1 and widget2 will be visible, or widget1 and widget4, so I don't know how to wrap them in Row.

I tried using GridView.count, but I run into problems when one of them is marked dirty and rebuilt. Even if I hardcode two widgets unconditionally, I run into this proble:

```
return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          IncrementDecrementNumber(label: config['optional'][1]['data_value'], value: vel1,
            onMinusPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                if (vel1 > 0)
                  vel1--;
              });
            },
            onPlusPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                vel1++;
              });
            },
          ),
          IncrementDecrementNumber(label: config['optional'][3]['data_value'], value: vel2,
            onMinusPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                if (vel2 > 0)
                  vel2--;
              });
            },
            onPlusPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                vel2++;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When I click any of the + or - buttons, this happens (and on every click the widgets are shrunk, until they disappear):

[image]

Is there a way to use GridView and prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this happens, but using GridView instead GridView.count seems to work without shrinking.

```
return Container(
    child: GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
      ),
      children: [
        IncrementDecrementNumber(label: config['optional'][1]['data_value'], value: vel1,
          onMinusPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              if (vel1 > 0)
                vel1--;
            });
          },
          onPlusPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              vel1++;
            });
          },
        ),
        IncrementDecrementNumber(label: config['optional'][3]['data_value'], value: vel2,
          onMinusPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              if (vel2 > 0)
                vel2--;
            });
          },
          onPlusPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              vel2++;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```